# MIDI.js - Unable to change instruments

Tags: javascript, midi

I am trying to initialize MIDI.js with a glockenspiel instead of the default acoustic piano.   But I am getting no sounds

I have glockenspiel-ogg.js and glockenspiel-mp3.js (downloaded from https://github.com/gleitz/midi-js-soundfonts )  in a directory called soundfont.

I am running the following code on window.onload.  Where am I going wrong?

```
MIDI.loadPlugin({
soundfontUrl: "soundfont/",
instrument: "glockenspiel",
callback: function() {
MIDI.programChange(0, 10); 
MIDI.noteOn(0, 35, 127, 0);
}
});
```

Comment: currently there is no more 'programChange' in midi.js. how else can i do so?

Answer (score 8):

Sorry for answer an old question, but I found a better solution:

put this after the plugin load:

```
MIDI.programChange(0, MIDI.GeneralMIDI.byName["instrument_name"].number);
```

Comment: Mine doesn't have `MIDI.GeneralMIDI`, but rather `MIDI.GM`.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, I was looking at a bad list for MIDI instrument codes.  The Wikipedia page here has correct codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_MIDI  I was trying to use number 10, but glockenspiel is number 9.  So, this line should be:

```
MIDI.programChange(0, 9);
```

Comment: currently there is no more 'programChange' in midi.js. how else can i do so?